# Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'lock:recurring-job:l' resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, redis, hangfire

I am getting the following exception while hangfire server is provisioning recurring jobs:

```
  [DistributedLockTimeoutException: Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'lock:recurring-job:AppJobId' resource.]
   Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisDistributedLock.RetryUntilTrue(Func`1 action, TimeSpan timeout) +442
   Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisDistributedLock..ctor(Func`1 databaseFactory, ILockExtender lockExtender, String resource, String lockToken, TimeSpan timeout) +165
   Hangfire.Pro.Redis.DistributedLockWrapper..ctor(RedisConnection connection, String resource, TimeSpan timeout) +142
   Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisConnection.AcquireDistributedLock(String resource, TimeSpan timeout) +52
   Hangfire.RecurringJobExtensions.AcquireDistributedRecurringJobLock(IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, TimeSpan timeout) +64
   Hangfire.RecurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(String recurringJobId, Job job, String cronExpression, RecurringJobOptions options) +172
   Hangfire.RecurringJobManagerExtensions.AddOrUpdate(IRecurringJobManager manager, String recurringJobId, Job job, String cronExpression) +95
   App.HangFire.Models.RecuringJobs.SetUpRecurringJobs() +2022
   App.HangFire.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +261

[HttpException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'lock:recurring-job:AppJobId' resource.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +517
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +185
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Timeout expired. The timeout elapsed prior to obtaining a distributed lock on the 'lock:recurring-job:AppJobId' resource.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +714
```

This is causing the background service to take a long time to load and eventually resulting in the exception of above; I am using Hangfire.Pro.Redis 2.7.1.0

Kindly help!!!

Comment: which version of the dotnet framework are you using here?

Comment: @SaikumarGummaluri .Net Framework version 4.6.1